# How to fix /dev/mapper/rhel-root doesn't exist issue at startup?

Tags: rhel, lvm, root-filesystem

I was trying to increase my `/dev/mapper/rhel-root` size. I have available 136GB of free space. For testing, from GNOME disk graphical interface, I mounted ext4, 2 GB and then unmount it. I used `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 1.8TB /dev/sda3` command to increase my `/dev/sda3` from 1.7TB to 1.8TB. I have `/dev/mapper/rhel-root`, `/dev/mapper/rhel-home`, `/dev/mapper/rhel-var`, `/dev/mapper/rhel-swap` under `/dev/sda3`. After that I used `lvextend -L+1G /dev/mapper/rhel-root` to increase the root from 100GB to 101GB. At this point I reboot the system as the system got frozen. Now when starting the PC at the startup it complains `/dev/mapper/rhel-root` doesn't exist. I tried logging into the rescue mode and activate the `sda3` filesystem but I can't activate the root but other 3 (`home`, `var`, `swap`) has activated. Can you suggest how can I fix the issue?

Thanks a lot for your time!

EDIT 1:
[image: rescue mode output]

Startup message:
[image: startup]

System log from `journalctl`
[image: log1]

[image: log2]

Filesystem before making any change:
[image: Before]

After (from rescue mode):
[image: After]

EDIT2: [Solution]
Steps followed: At rescue mode use `fdisk` to resize (d, n, t) `/dev/sda3`. then used `vgscan -ay /dev/sda3` to activate the LVs (`root`, `var`, `swap`, `home`). Then use `lvscan` to check whether all the LVs activated properly. Last time `root` was not activated because I didn't do `fdisk`. Finally `exit` the rescue mode and start the system normally and it starts properly. Now `df -Th` showing the same sizes for the LVs. So, I use `lvextend -L+99G /dev/mapper/rhel-root -r` (I wanted to add 99GB for the `root`) to extend and resize the `root`. DON'T forget `-r` option because that's put me in a lot of trouble.

Before & After:

```
[root@ldo etc]# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/home' [1.46 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/var' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/root' [101.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/swap' [96.00 GiB] inherit
[root@ldo ~]# df -Th
Filesystem            Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs              devtmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 tmpfs      32G   47M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 tmpfs      32G   12M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                 tmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root xfs       100G   76G   25G  76% /
/dev/sda2             xfs        10G  226M  9.8G   3% /boot
/dev/sda1             vfat       10G   11M   10G   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/rhel-home xfs       1.5T  130G  1.4T   9% /home
/dev/mapper/rhel-var  xfs        20G  3.9G   17G  20% /var
tmpfs                 tmpfs     6.3G   56K  6.3G   1% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb1             vfat       30G  4.5G   25G  16% /run/media/root/RHEL-7_8 SE
tmpfs                 tmpfs     6.3G   40K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
[root@ldo ~]# lvextend -L+99G /dev/mapper/rhel-root -r
  Size of logical volume rhel/root changed from 101.00 GiB (25856 extents) to 200.00 GiB (51200 extents).
  Logical volume rhel/root successfully resized.
meta-data=/dev/mapper/rhel-root  isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=6553600 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=26214400, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=12800, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 26214400 to 52428800
[root@ldo ~]# df -Th
Filesystem            Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs              devtmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 tmpfs      32G   46M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 tmpfs      32G   12M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                 tmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root xfs       200G   76G  125G  38% /
/dev/sda2             xfs        10G  226M  9.8G   3% /boot
/dev/sda1             vfat       10G   11M   10G   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/rhel-home xfs       1.5T  130G  1.4T   9% /home
/dev/mapper/rhel-var  xfs        20G  3.9G   17G  20% /var
tmpfs                 tmpfs     6.3G   56K  6.3G   1% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb1             vfat       30G  4.5G   25G  16% /run/media/root/RHEL-7_8 SE
tmpfs                 tmpfs     6.3G   40K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
[root@ldo ~]# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/home' [1.46 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/var' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/root' [200.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/swap' [96.00 GiB] inherit
```

Comment: Please add `lvs` and `vgs` output from the rescue mode to your question. Also there must be some error message better than "/dev/mapper/rhel-root doesn't exist", please also add full error message. If you try to activate the lv manually using `lvchange -ay rhel/root` what happens? Also I see one problem with your resize steps -- you didn't use the `-r|--resizefs` option for `lvextend` which means the filesystem was not resized a probably can't be mounted because of this.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny Thanks a lot for your response. I have added some details of my system. Can you please have a look? I am also adding my before and after Filesystem scenario in case that is necessary. Actually, my target was to increase the rhel-root from 100GB to 200GB. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You didn't resize the `/dev/sda3` partition, only the physical volume "format" on it. You need to resize the partition using `parted` or `fdisk` and then use `pvresize` to resize the LVM PV format to size of the partition using `pvresize /dev/sda3` (without `--setphysicalvolumesize` this will just adjust the size of the PV to the size of the partition). After this you should be able to activate the `rhel/root` logical volume.
2. You didn't resize filesystem on the `root` logical volume. Use `resize2fs /dev/mapper/rhel-root` to adjust the filesystem size to the size of the `root` LV (replace `resize2fs` with tool appropriate for filesystem on `rhel/root`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This solution is to the point and resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the PV into size greater than the partition it's actually housed in was a wrong thing to do, as Vojtech Trefny already explained.

Fortunately you did not resize the filesystem yet: that makes this easier to reverse.

In rescue mode, you will need to use `lvm vgchange -ay --partial --activationmode degraded` to get the `/dev/mapper/rhel-root` to show up. (These extra options allow activating LVs with parts apparently missing, and LVM does not want to do that unless specifically asked.)

You'll then need to mount it manually: `mount /dev/mapper/rhel-root /mnt/sysimage`.

After this, you will have access to LVM configuration archive located at `/etc/lvm/archive`. Since the root filesystem is now mounted at `/mnt/sysimage`, the actual path will be `/mnt/sysimage/etc/lvm/archive`. The configuration archive files are text files. Find the most recent archive file that has a line like this near the beginning:

```
description = "Created *before* executing 'pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 1.8TB /dev/sda3'"
```

Copy it to `/tmp` of the rescue environment (or anywhere outside `/mnt/sysimage` will do). Then unmount the problem filesystem: `umount /mnt/sysimage`.

Deactivate the VG for restoration: `lvm vgchange -an root`

Then restore the LVM configuration to what it used to be before your mistake:

```
lvm vgcfgrestore --file /tmp/<backupfile>.vg rhel
```

Now you should be able to reboot and be back where you started.

The right way to do the extension would be to either A) first extend the *partition* containing the PV, or B) if the free space on disk is not located immediately after the `sda3` partition, make the free space into a new partition, make that partition into a LVM PV (`pvcreate /dev/sdaX` where X is the new partition), then add that new PV into the existing VG: `vgextend rhel /dev/sdaX`. After that, you should be able to extend the root LV and then the filesystem inside it.

Comment: thanks for taking the time and writing the solution. I haven't tried the steps but it gives me insight into the issue. Hope others will find your explanation helpful too.